# What is the idiomatic way to convert a 1-tuple struct to the contained element?

Tags: rust, idioms

Let us say we have the following type:

```rust
struct Wrapper(Content);
```

Say that I often need to access the `Content` value of this type, destructuring it every time gets cumbersome quickly. What would be the idiomatic approach to unwrapping this value? I know of two approaches: implementing `Into<Content>` and implementing `Deref`. Maybe one of these is preferred? Or maybe there's some better-accepted way to do it?

Into approach:

```rust
impl Into<Content> for Wrapper {
    fn into(self) -> Content {
        let Wrapper(content) = self;
        content
    }
}

// ...

let content: Content = wrapper.into();
```

Deref approach:

```rust
impl Deref for Wrapper {
    type Target = Content;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        let Wrapper(content) = self;
        content
    }
}

// ...

let content: Content = *wrapper;
```

Comment: I usually write `&self.0`, did you consider that? Or are you talking about how to use this type from outside of the `Wrapper` implementation?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.tuple.html

Comment: Ahhh, I was trying `&self[0]` and getting errors. In either case, as much as possible I would like the wrapper type to be treated as the content type. So yeah, I want to often use it outside the wrapper.

Comment: @rodrigo If you believe that to be the appropriate approach, can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Be careful with abusing Deref. You won't always be able to follow what happens in your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Deref` is definitely *not* idiomatic. Quoting [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html):

> Implementing `Deref` for smart pointers makes accessing the data behind them convenient, which is why they implement `Deref`. On the other hand, the rules regarding `Deref` and `DerefMut` were designed specifically to accommodate smart pointers. Because of this, **`Deref` should only be implemented for smart pointers** to avoid confusion.

As long as the wrapper type is not a smart pointer (this definition is in flux;  [there is a very long discussion in the users forum about this subject](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/what-are-smart-pointers/67361). However, usually wrapper types are not smart pointers and it's easy to judge).

Implementing `Into` directly is not idiomatic either. You should implement `From` instead. Quoting [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.Into.html) again:

> One should avoid implementing `Into` and implement `From` instead. Implementing `From` automatically provides one with an implementation of `Into` thanks to the blanket implementation in the standard library.

What else do we have?

- Implementing [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html), [`AsMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsMut.html) and [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.From.html) for conversions.
- Use destructuring: `let Wrapper(v) = wrapper;`.
- Directly refer the field using the dot syntax: `wrapper.0`.

I recommend to implement the conversion traits `AsRef`, `AsMut` and `From` as necessary, but use either of destructuring or dot-syntax when not working with generics. Which to use is left to your opinion - there is no strong convention in the Rust community on that.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to access the element of a tuple or a tuple-struct is with the `.` syntax:

```
impl Wrapper {
    fn as_content(&self) -> &Content {
        &self.0
    }
}
```

Note that in a tuple-struct the `.0` pseudo-field is private by default, just like any other struct field. If you want to make it public, so that you do not need the `impl Deref`, use this syntax:

```
pub struct Wrapper(pub Content);
```

As for *idiomatic*, when a type can be seen as a reference to other type, is is customary to have a function `as_type`, as the one above. And if it can be *unwrapped* into that type, then `into_type`:

```
fn into_content(self) -> Content {
    self.0
}
```

You can also consider implementing `AsRef<Content>` and/or `Into<Content>`, but that would depend on the intented usage.